# Close the previous dropdown menu when click on the next dropdown menu opener button and keep that menu opened

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please see the page first to understand https://ibnul.neocities.org/_temporary/au2p10/au2p10.html

Here I have multiple dropdown menu which needs to open when clicked on their respective opener button(3 bar icon). And also it needs to close on either when clicked on the icon again or click somewhere else on the page.

So I have managed to open the menu when clicked on their respective button and also close when click again or click outside somewhere on the page.

But if I click the first button and without clicking the same button again or without clicking somewhere else on the page if I click the second button the second menu will open while the first menu is opened and also if I do the same for the third menu afterwards the third menu will also open while the previous two menu is opened. So you will see all three menu opened at the same time.

This is the problem. I want to close all the previous menus when click on the next menu button or close all the next menus when clicked on the previous menu button. The point is there should not be more than one menu visible at a time.

I want to open only the last one and the previous one should close when the next one is clicked so you cant see more than one dropdown menu at a time.

And also I don't want to add any id name on the html file as I need to copy paste this html code multiple time so you should give me a solution only through javascript which works with the same class name to identify elements where no matter how many time I copy pate the html code the menu will work the same and will not open more that one menu at a time.

And please show it in pure javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-US'>

<head>

  <title>au2p10</title>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

  <style>

    * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      font-family:'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .res-loc-shre-con {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      padding: 30px;
    }

    .edit-menu-icon-con {
      position: relative;
      margin: 10px 0px 70px 0px;
    }

    .edit-menu-text-icon-con {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .edit-menu-sdtext {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #0086bf;
      padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
    }

    .edit-menu-icon-image {
      width: 25px;
      height: 20px;
      padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    }

    .eidit-menu-icon-item-con {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 35px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 0.9px solid #dadada;
      padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
      width: 200px;
      min-height: 100px;
    }


    .edit-menu-drop-down-box {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 42px;
      right: -1px;
      width: 180px;
      padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 0.9px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);
      display: none;
    }

    .edit-menu-drop-down-box:focus {
      outline: 0px;
    }

    .show-edit-menu-drop-down-box {
      display: block;
    }

    .edit-menu-drop-down-cone-box {
      position: relative;
    }

    .edit-menu-dorp-down-cone {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      top: -11px;
      right: 9px;
      width: 14px;
      height: 14px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border-left: 0.9px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
      border-top: 0.9px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    .edit-menu-selectitem {
      display: flex;
      padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    }

    .edit-menu-selectitem:hover {
      background-color:  rgb(238, 238, 238);
    }

    .edit-menu-select-text {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #7c7c7c;
      padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<!-- start -->
<body>

<div class='res-loc-shre-con'>
  <div class='edit-menu-icon-con'>
    <div class='edit-menu-text-icon-con'>
      <p class='edit-menu-sdtext'>Manage au2</p>
      <img class='edit-menu-icon-image' src='menu-icon-blue.svg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='edit-menu-drop-down-box'>
      <div class='edit-menu-drop-down-cone-box'>
        <div class='edit-menu-dorp-down-cone'></div>
      </div>
      <a class='edit-menu-itemlink' href=''>
        <div class='edit-menu-selectitem'>
          <p class='edit-menu-select-text'>Edit</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class='edit-menu-itemlink' href=''>
        <div class='edit-menu-selectitem'>
          <p class='edit-menu-select-text'>Make Featured</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class='edit-menu-itemlink' href=''>
        <div class='edit-menu-selectitem'>
          <p class='edit-menu-select-text'>Comment</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='res-loc-shre-con'>
  <div class='edit-menu-icon-con'>
    <div class='edit-menu-text-icon-con'>
      <p class='edit-menu-sdtext'>Manage au2</p>
      <img class='edit-menu-icon-image' src='menu-icon-blue.svg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='edit-menu-drop-down-box'>
      <div class='edit-menu-drop-down-cone-box'>
        <div class='edit-menu-dorp-down-cone'></div>
      </div>
      <a class='edit-menu-itemlink' href=''>
        <div class='edit-menu-selectitem'>
          <p class='edit-menu-select-text'>Edit</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class='edit-menu-itemlink' href=''>
        <div class='edit-menu-selectitem'>
          <p class='edit-menu-select-text'>Make Featured</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class='edit-menu-itemlink' href=''>
        <div class='edit-menu-selectitem'>
          <p class='edit-menu-select-text'>Comment</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='res-loc-shre-con'>
  <div class='edit-menu-icon-con'>
    <div class='edit-menu-text-icon-con'>
      <p class='edit-menu-sdtext'>Manage au2</p>
      <img class='edit-menu-icon-image' src='menu-icon-blue.svg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='edit-menu-drop-down-box'>
      <div class='edit-menu-drop-down-cone-box'>
        <div class='edit-menu-dorp-down-cone'></div>
      </div>
      <a class='edit-menu-itemlink' href=''>
        <div class='edit-menu-selectitem'>
          <p class='edit-menu-select-text'>Edit</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class='edit-menu-itemlink' href=''>
        <div class='edit-menu-selectitem'>
          <p class='edit-menu-select-text'>Make Featured</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class='edit-menu-itemlink' href=''>
        <div class='edit-menu-selectitem'>
          <p class='edit-menu-select-text'>Comment</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

  var edit_menu_btns = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-menu-icon-image');
  edit_menu_btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', show_edit_menu_dropdown_box);
  });

  function show_edit_menu_dropdown_box(e) {
    var card = e.target.closest('.edit-menu-icon-con');
    var edit_menu_dropdown_box = card.querySelector('.edit-menu-drop-down-box');
    edit_menu_dropdown_box.classList.toggle('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box');

    window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.edit-menu-icon-image')) {
        var editMenuDropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-menu-drop-down-box');
        for (var j = 0; j < editMenuDropdowns.length; j++) {
          var openEditMenuDropdown = editMenuDropdowns[j];
          if (openEditMenuDropdown.classList.contains('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box')) {
            openEditMenuDropdown.classList.remove('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box');
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

</script>

</body>
```

I have put it in a single html file (https://ibnul.neocities.org/_temporary/au2p10/au2p10.html) so you can easily download the page and try on your code editor.
Please comment if you didn't understand any part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the eventlistener with this:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var editMenuDropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-menu-drop-down-box');
    for (var j = 0; j < editMenuDropdowns.length; j++) {
      var openEditMenuDropdown = editMenuDropdowns[j];
      if (openEditMenuDropdown.classList.contains('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box') && event.target.closest('.edit-menu-icon-con') !== openEditMenuDropdown.parentElement) {
        openEditMenuDropdown.classList.remove('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box');
      }
    }
});
```

All we're doing here is telling the "editMenuDropdowns" loop to not close the closest menu when clicked, but it'll close all other menus.

And Dennis is correct in that the eventlistener function is inside the function above it when it should be on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I wanted. An independent script that will take care of all the menus.

Comment: Glad to help! I once tackled this same issue with dropdown menus INSIDE dropdown menus so I know how much of a headache closing priority can be.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that closes all the menus, and call it each time any menu is clicked (you've already written that part). Then open the menu.

```
function closeAllMenus() {
    var editMenuDropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-menu-drop-down-box');
    for (var j = 0; j < editMenuDropdowns.length; j++) {
      var openEditMenuDropdown = editMenuDropdowns[j];
      if (openEditMenuDropdown.classList.contains('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box')) {
        openEditMenuDropdown.classList.remove('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box');
      }
   }
}
```

Also, I believe you are missing a curly brace at the end of your `show_edit_menu_dropdown_box` function.

Comment: Got your idea but I couldn't do it myself, I am a beginner on javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just close all the menu first before open one.

so please just add few lines in your code like this:

```
function show_edit_menu_dropdown_box(e) {
// Add blow lines
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".edit-menu-drop-down-box");
 cards.forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove("show-edit-menu-drop-down-box");
});

var card = e.target.closest('.edit-menu-icon-con');
var edit_menu_dropdown_box = card.querySelector('.edit-menu-drop-down-box');
edit_menu_dropdown_box.classList.toggle('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box');

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.edit-menu-icon-image')) {
    var editMenuDropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-menu-drop-down-box');
    for (var j = 0; j < editMenuDropdowns.length; j++) {
      var openEditMenuDropdown = editMenuDropdowns[j];
      if (openEditMenuDropdown.classList.contains('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box')) {
        openEditMenuDropdown.classList.remove('show-edit-menu-drop-down-box');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have checked this and it works fine.